# Search for an item in MixedCollection

Tags: javascript, search, extjs

I use Ext JS, so

I have a toolbar with items (buttons, labels etc). I add elements to the toolbar like this :

```
toolbar.add(this.tempObject);
```

or like this:

```
toolbar.add({
    xtype: button,
    ...
});
```

So, I want to find some elements in this toolbar by field `"ref"`. I tried to:

```
toolbar.items.find(new Function("there should be my function, but i have no idea how to write it"));
```

And there is no promice that every element in this collection will have this field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the findBy method:

```
toolbar.items.findBy(c => c.ref == 'the value you want');
```

There are other methods for talking about child items on containers, however it depends on the Ext version and what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe you know some refs, where I can see, how to make functions, like you've done?

Comment: It is called arrow function and is part of es6 see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions